# MVVM If statement

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-ui

I'm trying to render an form with Kendo MVVM. My model is not predefined, some variables are context depended. When loading a model without the variable Kendo failes.

```
    <table>
        <tbody data-bind="source: media" data-template="source-template">

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="source-template">
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: src" /></td>
        </tr>
    </script>
```

The following error is thrown (in Chrome):

```
    "TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined
        at binders.source.Binder.extend.render (<url>kendo.web.js?1389961074:10552:27)
        at binders.source.Binder.extend.refresh (<url>kendo.web.js?1389961074:10456:22)
        at Class.extend.bind (<url>kendo.web.js?1389961074:10254:18)
        at Class.extend.applyBinding (<url>kendo.web.js?1389961074:11257:28)
        at Class.extend.bind (<url>kendo.web.js?1389961074:11233:22)
        at bindElement (<url>kendo.web.js?1389961074:11459:20)
        at bindElement (<url>kendo.web.js?1389961074:11473:17)
        at bindElement (<url>kendo.web.js?1389961074:11473:17)
        at bindElement (<url>kendo.web.js?1389961074:11473:17)
        at bindElement (<url>kendo.web.js?1389961074:11473:17)"
```

I already hide this part when the media variable is not available but still the error is thrown.

Comment: What does "context dependent" mean? What does "loading a model without the variable" mean? It is rather unclear what you are doing and the provided code doesn't indicate that. Show us a more complete code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I thought it was clear. I'm sorry ;) (and I'm having trouble with stackoverflow ...)

I got multiple models. In some models the variable 'media' is ommited.

Model 1:

```
    {
        "type": "video",
        "edit": true
    }
```

Model 2:

```
    {
        "type": "video",
        "edit": true,
        "media": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "src": "<FILE>",
                    "mimetype": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

The sources array can contain multiple entries which need to render a list inside a table (see my first post).